# EffiProz Database ODBC

Tags: database, odbc

Can I use ODBC to connect to a EffiProz Database?

Comment: http://www.nucleonsoftware.com/DatabaseMaster.aspx

Comment: Nucleon Software provides a management tool, not an ODBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. - There is not ODBC driver for EffiProz databases.